# How to split a dataframe into multiple at the same time based on the value of one column

Tags: r, dataframe

```
crop.genos <- data.frame(crop=rep(1:6, each=4),genos=rep(1:4, 6))
crop.genos$crop.genotype <- paste(crop.genos$crop, crop.genos$genos, sep="")
```

Here I got a data frame with three columns: crop, genos, crop.geotype. And I want to get six different dataframe based on the crop catogory (such like the example below), all the rest columns are remained

```
   crop genos crop.genotype
1     1     1            11
2     1     2            12
3     1     3            13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split`:

```r
l <- split(crop.genos, crop.genos$crop)
names(l) <- paste0('df', names(l))
list2env(l, env = .GlobalEnv)
```

output

```r
> df1
#  crop genos crop.genotype
#1    1     1            11
#2    1     2            12
#3    1     3            13
#4    1     4            14
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i extract any of the dataframe?

Comment: You can use `list2env` to put all dataframes in your global environment. see edit